# How to find weight function using generating series?

Tags: combinatorics, formal-power-series

How to find the weight function and corresponding set given the generating series?

Is there a general method for this kind of problems, I am preparing for an olympiad. Consider the below example:

$\prod\limits_{k=0}^{99} (1+x^{1\cdot10k}+x^{2\cdot10k}+x^{3\cdot10k}+x^{4\cdot10k}+x^{5\cdot10k}+x^{6\cdot10k}+x^{7\cdot10k}+x^{8\cdot10k}+x^{9\cdot10k})$

How should I solve this? For simpler generating series it might be easy but for questions like this one, I am unable to come up with a  solution.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Are those decimal points or products in the exponents? That is, by $2.10k$ do you mean $\frac{21}{10}k$, or $20k$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott product, sorry i should have been more clear

Comment: Okay; I’ve replaced them with centre dots (`\cdot`), which in English usage indicate multiplication.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks:)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you have any idea for this question?

Comment: I’ve not yet had a chance to think seriously about it; I hope to get to it later tonight.

Comment: I can’t right now: I have to do some chores before I do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Before like terms are collected, a typical term of the product has an exponent of the form

$$a_0\cdot 10\cdot0+a_1\cdot10\cdot 1+\ldots+a_{99}\cdot10\cdot99=\sum_{k=0}^{99}10ka_k\;,$$

where each $a_k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$; we can take this to be the weight of one element of the set in question. There are many sets that could be made to work with a suitable definition of the weight function, but the simplest is $D^{100}$, where $D=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Each element of $D^{100}$ is a $100$-tuple $a=\langle a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{99}\rangle$, and we define

$$w(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{99}10ka_k\;.$$

Then

$$\sum_{a\in D^{100}}x^{w(a)}=\prod_{k=0}^{99}\sum_{i=0}^9x^{10ik}\;,$$

as desired. The element $a=\langle a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{99}\rangle\in D^{100}$ corresponds to the term $\prod_{k=0}^{100}x^{10a_kk}=x^{w(a)}$ in the expanded product on the righthand side.